# How to display an array of array in ionic 3

Tags: arrays, typescript, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to display the **array of array** data.

my API response:

```
{
  "product_id": "13",
  "is_master": "0",
  "sku": "Variable_product_15",
  "upc": "",
  "price": "40.00000",
  "pricing_calculator": "standard",
  "shipping": "0",
  "params": "{\"variant_main_image\":\"images\\/themeparrot\\/clothing_products_06.png\"}",
  "length": "0.00000",
  "width": "0.00000",
  "height": "0.00000",
}
```

In this array i need to display `variant_main_image`.

my **ts**:

```
variableprod() {
  let j2s = this.vproductsj2sid.find(x => x.j2store_variant_id === this.vprodid);
  console.log("show"+JSON.stringify(j2s));
  this.vcategorydata =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j2s.price));
  console.log(JSON.stringify("vname: "+JSON.stringify(this.vcategorydata)));
  this.vpdimages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j2s.params));
  this.vimg = this.vpdimages.variant_main_image; 
  console.log(JSON.stringify("vimg: "+JSON.stringify(this.vimg)));
}
```

in the log, it only shows **`"vimg: undefined"`**

Answer (score 0):

```
this.vpdimages = JSON.parse(j2s.params);
```

use JSON.parse() only instedad of

```
this.vpdimages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j2s.params));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let apiRespose = {
  "product_id": "13",
  "is_master": "0",
  "sku": "Variable_product_15",
  "upc": "",
  "price": "40.00000",
  "pricing_calculator": "standard",
  "shipping": "0",
  "params": "{\"variant_main_image\":\"images\\/themeparrot\\/clothing_products_06.png\"}",
  "length": "0.00000",
  "width": "0.00000",
  "height": "0.00000",
};

let receivedData = JSON.parse(apiRespose);
console.log(receivedData.variant_main_image)
```